# R: how to define a time variable, such as time=9:30?

Tags: r, time

In my date set, there is a string varing containing time, such as {"9:30", "10:01", ...}. How can I convert them so that they can be treated as time? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `times` from `chron`

```
library(chron)
times(paste(v1, '00', sep=':'))
#[1] 09:30:00 10:01:00
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('9:30', '10:01')
```